# Nodejs findOneAndUpdate paramerters

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a user model with the following schema, all fields required

```
name:String, 
country:String,
age:Number
```

From frontend i press update button and update only the age field, and on backend i have the following

```
var body = _.pick(req.body, ["candidateId","name","age","country"]);
var candidateId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body.candidateId);

Candidate.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id:candidateId
    },{
        name: body.name,
        country: body.country,
        age: body.age,
    }).then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
            res.status(400).send('noDataFound');
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    })
```

Front passes the data as follows

```
{   "candidateId":"5a9a86c16acff45a8070d2da",
     "name":"Superman",
}
```

I will get get undefined error for body.age and body.country since its not passed from front end.

**QUESTION - How can use the previous values if no value is send from front end for some parameter, one approach is to send everything even if its not changed.**

Comment: I haven't used mongoose so I have a question. Can you only update `name` value for the found object?

Comment: I can update for everything , but then front end will have to send all the old data also.. i want a approach where the frontend passes only the new data

Comment: What I meant to ask was, can you selectively update fields of found object by using `findOneAndUpdate`? Or do you need to specify a value for every field the found object has?

Comment: yes can do that. the findOneAndUpdate basically needs a Key-Value pair of the values to update.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using lodash, check out [omitBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#omitBy) to remove undefined or null properties:

```
_.omitBy({ foo: 'foo', bar: undefined, baz: null }, _.isNil)
{foo: "foo"}
```

Here's a vanilla JS solution:

```
Object
  .entries({ foo: 'foo', bar: undefined, baz: null })
  .filter(([_, value]) => value !== null && value !== undefined)
  .reduce((acc, [key, value]) => { acc[key] = value; return acc; }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Form a new object that includes sent values:

```
const newObj = {};

if (body.name) {
  newObj.name = body.name;
}

if (body.age) {
  newObj.age = body.age;
}

if (body.country) {
  newObj.country = body.country;
}
```

Then update using `newObj`.

```
Candidate.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id:candidateId
    }, newObj)...
```

Answer (score 0):

When I'm facing this problem I usually create a parser function as:

```
var body = _.pick(req.body, ["candidateId","name","age","country"]);
var candidateId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body.candidateId);

function createUpdatedValues(params) {
  var condition = {};
  if (params.candidateId) condition.candidateId = params.candidateId;
  if (params.name) condition.name = params.name;
  if (params.age) condition.age = params.age;
  if (params.country) condition.country = params.country;
  return condition;
}    

Candidate.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id:candidateId
    },createUpdatedValues(body)).then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
            res.status(400).send('noDataFound');
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    })
```

Comment: Yea , that will work.. but i have a lot of values to submit 15-20 , so this will become untidy soon... any other approach ? one way i can think is get the current data and perform a merge and then update the data..

Comment: but the issue is the time increases since again have to fetch data from DB and merge..

Comment: Yeah, you could use findOne to get this object, update it with new values, then use findOneAndUpdate, which I don’t recommend since it takes longer

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following way to go around it , if any other better approach is there let me know ill mark that as answer.

I am now passing all the data to update from frontend in a new object like this

--- Client Data---

```
{   "candidateId":"5a9a86c16acff45a8070d2da",
    "updatedData":{
        "firstName":"Jack",
        "lastName":"Bauer",
        "applicationSource":"consultant",
        "skills":["trading","sales"]    
    }
}
```

---- Updating logic ----

```
var body = _.pick(req.body, ["candidateId","updatedData"]);
    var candidateId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(body.candidateId);

    var dataToUpdate = _.pick(body.updatedData,["firstName","lastName"]);

    Candidate.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id:candidateId
    },dataToUpdate).then((data) => {
        if (!data) {
            res.status(400).send('noDataFound');
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        res.status(500).send(e)
    })
```